# Could NOT find MPI_C and MPI cmake on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, c, cmake, mpi, ubuntu-16.04

```
- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1")
-- Checking for module 'libusb-1.0>=1.0.17'
--   Found libusb-1.0, version 1.0.21
-- Checking for module 'opencv>=3.0'
--   Found opencv, version 3.2.0
-- Checking for module 'libcaer>=2.0'
--   Found libcaer, version 3.3.7
-- Could NOT find MPI_C (missing: MPI_C_WORKS)
-- Found MPI_CXX: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi_cxx.so (found version "3.1")
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI (missing: MPI_C_FOUND) (found version "3.1")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:1444 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:193 (find_package)
```

Tried everything exported the paths done everything I've found on google still have this annoying error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
cmake is already the newest version (3.10.2-1ubuntu2.18.04.1).
```

Which command results:

```
endrel@Siraly:~/Developer/BrainHarmonics/build$ which mpicc
/usr/bin/mpicc
endrel@Siraly:~/Developer/BrainHarmonics/build$ which mpicxx
/usr/bin/mpicxx
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log` from your build directory?

Answer (score 1):

From [FindMPI.cmake module](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/FindMPI.cmake):

> If the find procedure fails for a variable `MPI_<lang>_WORKS`, then the settings detected by or passed to the module did not work and even a simple MPI test program failed to compile.

> -- Could NOT find MPI_C (missing: MPI_C_WORKS)

Your mpicc is found but probably not working correctly.

Maybe your `CMakeLists.txt` is wrong, but you didn't provide it's content, so it's hard to say.