# Could not find "MPI_C library names, header directory and its works" on Windows 10

Tags: windows, cmake, mpi

everyone!

I got a similar problem when I was trying to install  *relion* on my own windows 10 ([Could NOT find MPI_C and MPI cmake on Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63087881/could-not-find-mpi-c-and-mpi-cmake-on-ubuntu-18-04) and [CMake could not found MPI_C MPI_CXX on centos 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66205579/cmake-could-not-found-mpi-c-mpi-cxx-on-centos-7)) as my error output is

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
-- BUILD TYPE set to the default type:  'Release'
-- Setting fallback CUDA_ARCH=35
-- ALLOW_CTF_IN_SAGD enabled - This build of RELION allows modulation of particle images by a contrast transfer function inside stochastic average gradient descent, as specified in Claim 1 of patent US10,282,513B2
-- CUDA enabled - Building CUDA-accelerated version of RELION
-- Setting cpu precision to double
-- Setting accelerated code precision to single
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
-- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY)
-- Using non-cuda compilation....
-- Could NOT find MPI_C (missing: MPI_C_LIB_NAMES MPI_C_HEADER_DIR MPI_C_WORKS)
-- Could NOT find MPI_CXX (missing: MPI_CXX_LIB_NAMES MPI_CXX_HEADER_DIR MPI_CXX_WORKS)
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI (missing: MPI_C_FOUND MPI_CXX_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:1742 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:215 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

**Also, I checked the commands as suggested**

```
>which mpicxx
/usr/bin/mpicxx

>which mpicc
/usr/bin/mpicc
```

The solutions there seem all point to `CMakeError.log`. However, the log file contains a lot of information, which may not be necessary to copy-paste all of it here. See below for a part of the log file. Hope it will be helpful

```
C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.20\Modules\FindMPI\test_mpi.c(1,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mpi.h': No such file or directory
```